# Sequence of String and its Implementation

Tags: c, cs50

I have a little tiny trouble with implementing a shift. Here is the idea of what I'm trying to do:
Given a string of number like 012345, given a specific condition, the sequence will shift from
012345
001234.Can somebody show me why the code didn't work and how can I fix this.

```
for(int a = i; a < (strlen(input)); a++)
                if (a < strlen(input) - 2)
                    {
                        holder  = key[a+1];
                        key[a+1]  = key[a];
                        key[a+2] = holder; 
                    }
        }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Double call to `strlen` is useless. Store the value into a variable.

Comment: `key[a+2]` addresses the string out of bounds when `a` is `>= strlen(input)-1` assuming `key` is `input`.

Comment: You should think to use a reverse for, starting from last char of string assigning the `string[index] = string[index-1];`

Answer (score 0):

To shift right a string you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift_r_str (char *string, size_t len, uint8_t shift);

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "012345";

    shift_r_str(input, strlen(input), 1);
    printf("Shifted: %s\n", input);

    shift_r_str(input, strlen(input), 2);
    printf("Shifted: %s\n", input);

}

void shift_r_str (char *string, size_t len, uint8_t shift)
{
    size_t i;

    if (len < shift)
    {
        shift = len;
    }

    for (i=len-1; ((i>0) && (i>=shift)); i--)
    {
        string[i] = string[i-shift];
    }

    for (i=0; i<shift; i++)
    {
        string[i] = '0';
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
Shifted: 001234
Shifted: 000012
```